# HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm trying to make a POST or PUT request to a WCF Service from IE and Fiddler but I’m receiving this error. HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required. So in IE and Fiddler, how do I add the Content-Length to my request?

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer,

You can’t add Content-Length to a URI when typed into a browser, “because by default it will perform a GET”!!! To add Content-Length to your header you must use a debugging tool, e.g.. Fiddler or build a form or some other type of client!

In fiddler you simply type Content-Length: 0 in the “Request Headers” section of the “Request Builder” and it will magically work! As seen near the bottom of this tutorial:

http://blog.donnfelker.com/2008/12/04/how-to-rest-services-in-wcf-3-5-part-2-the-post/